# The complexity of checking whether two DAG have the same number of topological sorts

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, counting-complexity, open-problem, partial-order

This problem is highly related to the [CNF](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/the-complexity-of-checking-whether-two-cnf-have-the-same-number-of-solutions) one.

Here is the problem: given two DAG (directed acyclic graphs), if they have the same counting of topological sorts, answer "Yes", otherwise, answer "No".

Intuitively, the complexity of this problem is [$C_=P$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#cequalsp)-complete, just as the [CNF](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/the-complexity-of-checking-whether-two-cnf-have-the-same-number-of-solutions) one. It is easy to see it is in $C_=P$, but is it $C_=P$-hard?

Comment: @Mike Chen Could you, please, explain what is $C_=P$? And what do you mean by the "counting of topological sorts"?

Comment: @Oleksandr: I added a link to $C_=P$ in the question. "counting of topological sorts" means the number of topological sorts.

Comment: @Mike Chen As I understood by the "counting of topological sorts" you mean the number of linear extensions of a given partial order, don't you? According to http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=intitle:%22Counting++Linear++Extensions%22&btnG=Search&as_sdt=2001&as_ylo=&as_vis=0 the problem of counting the number of linear extensions of a partially ordered set is $\sharp P$-complete.

Comment: @Mike Chen Thank you for clarification on $C_=P$! Intuitively, your problem is not easier than the counting of linear extensions.

Comment: Right, the counting version of this problem is $\#P$-complete. But what I really wanna know is if counting of solutions is $\#P$-complete, is the problem of deciding whether two have the same number of solutions $C_=P$-complete?

Comment: You probably already know this, but let me write this down for others: this problem is not (apparently) the same as the other question on [deciding whether two CNF formulas have the same number of solutions](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3059).  The reason is that counting the solutions to a given CNF formula is #P-complete _under parsimonious reductions_ whereas counting the topological sorts of a given DAG is not (unless P=NP).  Counting the topological sorts is #P-complete only under functional reductions between counting problems (also called weakly parsimonious reductions).

Comment: This is loosely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/793098 in the following sense: if you can answer this last question in the positive, then it should be hard to decide whether an input poset $P$ has *more* or *less* linear extensions than an input poset $P'$, as you can do a binary search to count linear extensions using an algorithm for this last problem and an algorithm to build posets with known number of linear extensions. (OK, deciding *less* or *more* is still not the same as deciding if the number is *exactly* equal.)

Comment: Somewhat related: Deciding whether two unweighted graphs have the same number of perfect matchings is C=P-complete. Like in your problem, the counting problem here is also not #P-complete under parsimonious reductions. http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07480

Comment: The C=P is now broken and was probably moved to https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:C#:~:text=C%3DP%3A%20Exact%2DCounting,coNQP%20%5BFGH%2B98%5D.